# How to retrieve hrSWRuntable using snmp in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, snmp, pid, pysnmp, oid

I just installed snmp on my machine using

```
apt-get install snmp
```

I want to retrieve the hrSWRuntable so I used this command

```
snmptable -v2c -c public 104.236.166.95 hrSWRunTable
```

but i recieved this error

```
hrSWRunTable: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> hrSWRunTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try referring to the MIB containing that MIB object:

```
snmptable -v2c -c public demo.snmplabs.com HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunTable
```

Alternatively, you can preload all MIBs you have with `-m ALL` option.